# Merge two *.jtl file of test report running on different machines

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load-testing

How can i merge reports of same script running on different machines using j meter.
i Avoid remote testing but having issue in get combined result at one place  while script  running from all machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use a decent merge program like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/)
- Write a merge script
- Use [remote testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) as recommended